# Iterate data structure while it is updated

Tags: python, yield

What is the correct way to iterate over a data structure in python while elements are removed from the structure at the same time?

I want to iterate over the `someList` structure and make sure to reach all items in the list as long as they are in the list and remove some of the items while I iterate it. But I don't understand why some numbers are skipped and how I can avoid this, resp. make sure to actually see each element in the list exactly once, under the condition, that it was not removed in advance. In the example I never saw `1`, `5`, and `8`

```
class someList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = list(range(0,10))

    def getData(self):
        for i in self.list:
            print(i)
            yield i

thing = someList()
for a in thing.getData():
    print("we reached:", a)
    if a % 2 == 1:
        print("remove", a)
        thing.list.remove(a)
    elif (a * 2) in thing.list:
        print("remove double a:", a, " a*2:", a * 2)
        thing.list.remove(a*2)
print(thing.list)
```

Output:

```
0
we reached: 0
remove double a: 0  a*2: 0
2
we reached: 2
remove double a: 2  a*2: 4
3
we reached: 3
remove 3
6
we reached: 6
7
we reached: 7
remove 7
9
we reached: 9
remove 9
[1, 2, 5, 6, 8]
```

Intended Output:

```
0
we reached: 0
remove double a: 0  a*2: 0
1
we reached: 1
remove 1
2
we reached: 2
remove double a: 2  a*2: 4
3
we reached: 3
remove 3
5
we reached: 5
remove 5
6
we reached: 6
7
we reached: 7
remove 7
8
we reached: 8
9
we reached: 9
remove 9
[2, 6, 8]
```

Note: this is not the same question as [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating) because I do not want to filter out the elements before I iterate.

The two modifying conditions are just examples as I indeed do iterate over a graph data structure, consume the current element and remove some elements that have a specific relation to the current element.

Comment: Why don't you want to create a new list without the elements? You can even re-assign the new list to the original list via a slice `[:]`

Comment: If you are iterating a updating a `list`, you can do it using `list.copy()`.

Comment: Don't; build a new list by adding the elements you want to keep, rather than removing the elements you don't want from the original list.

Comment: I don't want to copy the data structure because it can be huge.
I also can't just add the selected items to a new structure, because I need to remove connected elements, which are not yet visited, to not visit them later on.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, if you try to modify the list at runtime you'll not get correct itiration, so instead use another list to store what you want to remove,

```py
class someList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = list(range(0,10))

    def getData(self):
        for i in self.list:
            print(i)
            yield i

thing = someList()
rem_list=[]
for a in thing.getData():
    print("we reached:", a)
    if a in rem_list:
        pass
    elif a % 2 == 1:
        print("remove", a)
        rem_list.append(a)
    elif (a * 2) in thing.list:
        print("remove double a:", a, " a*2:", a * 2)
        rem_list.append(2*a)
thing.list=[x for x in thing.list if x not in rem_list]
print(thing.list) #outputs [2, 6, 8]
```

using the rem_list to store the to-be-removed members and not checking them in loop will give you expected result..